# puppeteer return value that is selected in dropdown

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

How can I grab the selected value from a dropdown (the value that is shown on the page)

```
<div class="form">
    <select name="stock" id="quantity_db" class="js_quantity_dropdown">
        <option value="1" >1</option>
        <option value="2" >2</option>
        <option value="3" >3</option>
        <option value="4" >4</option>
        <option value="5" >5</option>
        <option value="6" selected="selected">6</option>
    </select>
```

I have the following code.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
 const page = await browser.newPage();
 await page.goto('https://.....');

 const option  = await page.evaluate(()=> { 
 document.getElementById("quantity_db").options[document.getElementById("quantity_db").selectedIndex].text; });

console.log('Selected option is:', option)
})();
```

What I get when I run this is:

```
Selected option is: undefined
```

So that's not working...

UPDATE: Since the html page is very long I've added it to a fiddle jsfiddle.net/cad231/c14mnp6z The id of the select item is of which I would like to obtain the value : #tst_quantity_dropdown

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use puppeteer `$eval`. https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1

Select element by id and just ask for it's value will give you the selected value in the dropdown.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://afrekenen.bol.com/nl/winkelwagentje/direct-toevoegen?id=1001024332369558:2');

  const option = await page.$eval("#tst_quantity_dropdown", node => 
     node.value);
  console.log('Selected option is:', option)
})();
```

Ouputs: `Selected option is: 2`

Answer (score 0):

You could target selected instead.

```
document.querySelector('option[selected="selected"]').innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out..

Although as mentioned in the comments if the element you are trying to get is nested more than the example you gave then I recommend going to the web-page ans copy/pasting the "full JS path" from the elements you need to check (the options in this case)

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://....');

    const option  = await page.evaluate(()=> {

        //If this form is nested more than the code you provided then just go to the element in DevTools > right click > copy > full JS path.... This will give you the exact path the the form / form elements 
        var opts = document.querySelectorAll("#mainContent > div.shopping-cart > div > div > div.product__actions > div > div > div.product-actions__amount > div > form > fieldset > div.fluid-grid__item.h-relative > div > #tst_quantity_dropdown> option");
        var selected;
        //Check if each option has the "selected" attribute or not 
        opts.forEach(opt => {
            if(opt.hasAttribute('selected')){
                selected = opt.textContent;
            }
        });

        return selected;
    });
    
    //Wait for result and log it outside of the evaluate function
    let result = await option;

    console.log(result)

})();
```

Comment: The form is indeed deeply nested, tried the full js path, couldn't get that to work either. I tried including the full html page, but it is too long. I've added the html page to a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cad231/c14mnp6z/   The id of the select item is : #tst_quantity_dropdown

Comment: I went to the website and I'm assuming your trying to get the selected option in the search results. I was able to get a nodelist of all the options with ............................................."document.querySelectorAll("#js_items_content > li > div.product-item__content > wsp-buy-block > div.medium--is-visible--flex.js_product_actions > wsp-quantity-dropdown")"                        If this doesn't work, include the actual URL you want to parse and iI'll try to help.

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the amount of items in the cart. For example, this link will add 2 items to the cart: https://afrekenen.bol.com/nl/winkelwagentje/direct-toevoegen?id=1001024332369558:2 (I accept the cookie with puppeteer, which works fine). Id of the dropdown: tst_quantity_dropdown. Path: document.querySelector("#mainContent > div.shopping-cart > div > div > div.product__actions > div > div > div.product-actions__amount > div > form > fieldset > div.fluid-grid__item.h-relative > div > #tst_quantity_dropdown")  but puppeteer doesn't seem able to find the item.

Comment: just wanted to add, I tried adding this line: await page.waitForSelector("#tst_quantity_dropdown");  and it doesn't time out, which to me means it does locate the item.

Comment: I checked out the url and updated the example above. I cant actually cause I didn't send any cookies but hopefully this should work out for ya.